# How to fetch the correct students with the highest scores

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the highest score in a particular subject and then display the name of the student that has that highest score.

I have the query which gets the highest scores in each subjects in a class but it's not getting the correct student_id.

This is my query:

```
$subjectMaxQry = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT `student_id`, max(".$totField.") AS highest, 
                (SELECT firstname FROM students WHERE students.id = student_id) AS firstname, 
                (SELECT lastname FROM students WHERE students.id = student_id) AS lastname 
        FROM ".$table." 
        WHERE `session_id` = '".$sch_setting->session_id."' 
        AND `class_id` = '".$class_id."' 
        AND `subject_id` = '".$subName['sub_id']."'");

$highestMark = $subjectMaxQry->row_array();
```

The query shows the highest score of each subjects in a class but the issue is that the student's name being displayed is wrong. It does not show the student's name with the highest score in a subject.

Comment: Please add sample records, and what the expected return should be.

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question with data examples, expected result, and what MySQL version are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please read up on [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in PHP. At the moment, your code is most likely prone to SQL injections. Using prepared statements mitigates this security risk.

As for your query itself, you could use something like this:

```sql
SELECT a.student_id, students.firstname, students.lastname, a.score
FROM scores a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT class_id, subject_id, MAX(score) score
    FROM scores
    GROUP BY class_id, subject_id
) b 
ON a.score = b.score 
AND a.class_id = b.class_id 
AND a.subject_id = b.subject_id
INNER JOIN students ON students.id=a.student_id
WHERE a.class_id = 1
AND a.subject_id = 1
```

This query performs an inner join on itself to find out the maximum score per `class_id` and `subject_id` and joins on those fields to get the actual data in the table with the highest score. Then, another join is included to get the data from the `students` table.

You can use the `a.class_id=1` and `a.subject_id=1` lines to filter and the desired classes and subjects.

You can check this [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aaGrqs4bXomWdotqm7okXe/0) to play around with it.

Comment: This works fine but I just noticed that it doesn't fetch all the records. For some reasons, some subjects are being omitted. I'm only using ```a.class_id=1``` to filter, so It should fetch all subjects

Comment: This seems to be working correctly for me. I updated the DB fiddle with the new filter (and added `subject_id` to the output): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aaGrqs4bXomWdotqm7okXe/1 This outputs the records for both `subject_id` 1 and 2.